# All connections are aborted I don't know why my android device are rooted and the certificate are installed

Tags: http-toolkit

All connections are aborted I don't know why my android device are rooted and the certificate are installed for a long time. this happens with no errors nothing is that a bug?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now resolved [on GitHub](https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit/issues/566) but I'll copy my answer here too:

> Hard to know what this could be I'm afraid. It's possible this could happen due to issues on your network connection, or other interception software on your machine, that is actively blocking connections to all servers. It's also possible with some custom rule configurations, but I think you'd notice if you'd created a rule like that (e.g. a rule redirecting all traffic to a server that always rejects connections).